# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException when using YouTubePlayerView

Tags: java, android, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

Here is the code that uses the youtube api:

```
public class ArticleAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private ArrayList<ArticlePart> articlePartList;
    private Activity activity;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public ArticleAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<ArticlePart> articlePartList) {
        this.activity = activity;
            this.articlePartList = articlePartList;
            layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(activity);

            if (articlePartList == null) {
                Log.i("articlePartList", "null");
            }
    }

    ...
    ...

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

        final ArticlePart articlePart = articlePartList.get(position);
            String articlePartKind = articlePart.getKind();
            View view = null;

            String[] leaves = {"text", "richtext"};

            if (articlePartKind.equals("video_entry")) {


                final String videoId = "blabla";
                YouTubePlayerView ytPlayerView = new YouTubePlayerView(activity);
                view = ytPlayerView;
                ytPlayerView.initialize("apikey", new OnInitializedListener() {

                @Override
                    public void onInitializationFailure(Provider arg0, YouTubeInitializationResult arg1) {
                        Log.e("ArticleAdapter", "onInitializationFailure");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
                        Log.e("ArticleAdapter", "onInitializationSuccess");
                        player.cueVideo(videoId);
                    }
                });

            }

            view.setTag(R.id.tag_article_part_id, articlePart.getId());
            return view;
    }
}
```

The player view initially loads (I can see a black rectangle with a "loading" image in the middle) but my app hangs and crashes shortly after that.

This is what happens:

```
06-11 16:44:59.495  11097-11097/app E/dalvikvm~U Could not find class 'com.google.android.apps.youtube.core.player.overlay.bm', referenced from method ccgom.google.android.apps.youtube.core.player.overlay.SubtitlesPreferences.<init>
06-11 16:44:59.500  11097-11097/app E/dalvikvm~U Could not find class 'android.view.accessibility.CaptioningManager', referenced from method com.google..randroid.apps.youtube.core.player.overlay.SubtitlesPreferences.c
06-11 16:44:59.545  11763-11763/? E/dalvikvm~U Could not find class 'com.google.android.apps.youtube.core.player.overlay.bm', referenced from method commo.google.android.apps.youtube.core.player.overlay.SubtitlesPreferences.<init>
06-11 16:44:59.545  11763-11763/? E/dalvikvm~U Could not find class 'android.view.accessibility.CaptioningManager', referenced from method com.google.annidroid.apps.youtube.core.player.overlay.SubtitlesPreferences.c
06-11 16:44:59.580  11763-11763/? E/YouTubeAndroidPlayerAPI~U apps.youtube.core.player.Director.F:521 Media progress reported outside media playback
06-11 16:44:59.635  11763-11763/? E/AndroidRuntime~U FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
            at com.google.android.apps.youtube.core.utils.ab.a(SourceFile:112)
            at com.google.android.apps.youtube.core.player.a.a.a(SourceFile:92)
            at com.google.android.apps.youtube.core.player.sequencer.o.a(SourceFile:212)
            at com.google.android.apps.youtube.core.player.sequencer.o.g(SourceFile:116)
            at com.google.android.apps.youtube.core.player.sequencer.o.i(SourceFile:128)
            at com.google.android.apps.youtube.core.player.Director.o(SourceFile:801)
            at com.google.android.apps.youtube.core.player.Director.a(SourceFile:629)
            at com.google.android.apps.youtube.api.ApiPlayer.b(SourceFile:297)
            at com.google.android.apps.youtube.api.b.a.p.run(SourceFile:210)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

here is a link to the whole thing - no filters, just searching for "youtube" in logcat:
http://pastebin.com/6DjBbn0B

I tried using loadVideo() instead of cueVideo() and surrounding the cueVideo() in a try/catch block as suggested here https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=4395 but that did not help.